# Docker swarm and service discovery

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm moving away from docker-compose files to using docker swarm but I just can't figure this out.

I have two services - a nginx proxy, and a website both running just fine in docker swarm (which has three nodes)

The issue I've got is I need to configure nginx to proxy_pass to the backend website. Currently the only way I can get this to work is by specifying an ip address of one of the nodes.

My services are created as follows:

`docker service create --mount type=bind,source=/../nginx.conf,target=/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf \
-p 443:443 \
--name nginx \ 
nginx`

and

`docker service create --name ynab \
-p 5000:5000 \
--replicas 2 \
scottrobertson/fintech-to-ynab`

I've tried using the service name but that just doesn't work.

Really I don't think I should have to even expose the ynab service ports (at least that would work when I used docker-compose)

In one of the nginx containers I have tried the following:

`root@5fabc5611264:/# curl http://ynab:5000/ping
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ynab
root@5fabc5611264:/# curl http://nginx:5000/ping
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: nginx
root@5fabc5611264:/# curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/ping
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 5000: Connection refused
root@5fabc5611264:/# curl http://localhost:5000/ping
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 5000: Connection refused`

Using the process list I tried connecting to the running instances id, and name:

`root@5fabc5611264:/# curl http://ynab.1:5000/ping
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ynab.1
root@5fabc5611264:/# curl http://pj0ekc6i7n0v:5000/ping
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: pj0ekc6i7n0v`

But I can only get it to work if I use the nodes public ip addresses:

`root@5fabc5611264:/# curl http://192.168.1.52:5000/ping
pong
root@5fabc5611264:/# curl http://192.168.1.53:5000/ping
pong
root@5fabc5611264:/# curl http://192.168.1.51:5000/ping
pong`

I really don't want to use a public ip in case that node goes down. I'm sure I must just be doing something wrong!

Comment: Not tested but you need to put them on the same network iirc. `docker network create -d overlay my-net`, `docker service create --network my-net ...`

Comment: You are correct! thats what it was - Add it as an answer so I can give you fake internet points!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The services need to be connected to the same network for this to work.

```
$ docker network create -d overlay fake-internet-points
$ docker service create --name service_one --network fake-internet-points [...]
$ docker service create --name service_two --network fake-internet-points [...]
```